# What's the worst case of random search

Tags: sorting

What's the worst case of random search? Say I have N elements, then search for one particular element.

Is the answer infinite? That makes sense to me, since I never find the element in worst case.

Then best case is just 1 right? What about average then?

Comment: Do you really mean random search? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_search or do you mean a linear search on a randomly arranged array, or do you mean randomly choosing indices into an array (and allow repeated indices)? From context I'd assume the latter but you may want to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your in effect doing a simple random sample of the set. The chance any given element is selected after n samples selected from N elements is given by:

```
P(n) = 1 - (1 - 1/N)^n
```

Wikipedia article on [Simple Random Sample](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_random_sample).